# Count number of steps of turtle in a list - python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, turtle-graphics

I am now three weeks into learning python and I'm stuck. 
This is my code: (after that comes my question)

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

def person_characteristics(people):
    """ 
    Gives the turtle 'person' all it's characteristics / values. 
    """
    for person in people:
        person.shape('circle')
        person.shapesize(0.2)
        person.speed('fastest')
        person.penup()
        x = randint(-200, 200) #turtle gets a random position
        y = randint(-200, 200)
        person.setpos(x, y)
        person.showturtle()

def population(population_size):
    """
    Makes a population, by making a list of turtles (persons). 
    population_size = type(int)
    """
    people = []

    for _ in range(population_size):
        people.append(Turtle(visible=False))

    return people

def random_walk(person, step_size, area_size):
    """
    Makes the person walk around randomly within the borders. 
    step_size = type(int) -> determines how big of a step each person takes. 
    area_size = type(int) -> determines how big the area is where the persons are in.
    """
    if -area_size < person.xcor() < area_size and -area_size < person.ycor() < area_size: #if person is within the borders then it moves randomly
        person.right(randint(0, 360))
        person.forward(step_size)
    else:
        person.right(180) #if person is outside the borders it turns around
        person.forward(step_size)

def infect_random(people): 
    """
   Random person gets infected (a red color)
    people = a list of persons achieved from de function population()
    """
    infected = choice(people)
    infected.color('red')
    return infected

screen = Screen()

people = population(100)
person_characteristics(people)

infected_people = []
initial_infected = infect_random(people)
infected_people.append(initial_infected)


counted_infections = 1
#count_steps = 0
#healed_people = []

for _ in range(10): # determines the number of steps = time
    for person in people:
        random_walk(person, 30, 400)

        for infected_person in infected_people:
            if person.pencolor() != 'red' and person.distance(infected_person) < 30:  #if a person gets close to the initial infected person it also
                person.color('red')                                                   #gets infected & added to the list of infected persons
                infected_people.append(person)
                #count_steps +=1 
                #if count_steps = 5:
                    #infected_person.color('green')
                    #healed_people.append(infected_person)
                    #infected_people.remove(infected_person) 
                break 


count_susceptible = len(people) - len(infected_people)                          #counts number of susceptible people
count_infected = len(infected_people)                                           #counts number of infected people

print(count_susceptible)
print(count_infected)

screen.exitonclick()
```

I want to turn the infected_person green (=healed) and at the turtle to the list healed_people (& remove from the list infected_people) after it made 5 steps. My idea was to do this with a if statement however this does not work. My idea is in the code above. I know why it doesn't work: now it counts the total number of steps of every infected_person, instead of separately.
I think there probably is a very simple solution but I am very new to python so I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

(I prefer not to use a Class since I didn't learn that yet :)

Comment: Well, think about it logically: if you have N people, how many counts of steps do you need? Can you think of an elegant way to store that? (hint: how are you storing N people in a single variable already?) Then, can you think of a way to associate a given step-count with the correct person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

def person_characteristics(people):
    """ 
    Gives the turtle 'person' all it's characteristics / values. 
    """
    for person in people:
        person.shape('circle')
        person.shapesize(0.2)
        person.speed('fastest')
        person.penup()
        x = randint(-200, 200) #turtle gets a random position
        y = randint(-200, 200)
        person.setpos(x, y)
        person.showturtle()

def population(population_size):
    """
    Makes a population, by making a list of turtles (persons). 
    population_size = type(int)
    """
    people = []

    for _ in range(population_size):
        people.append(Turtle(visible=False))

    return people

def random_walk(person, step_size, area_size):
    """
    Makes the person walk around randomly within the borders. 
    step_size = type(int) -> determines how big of a step each person takes. 
    area_size = type(int) -> determines how big the area is where the persons are in.
    """
    if -area_size < person.xcor() < area_size and -area_size < person.ycor() < area_size: #if person is within the borders then it moves randomly
        person.right(randint(0, 360))
        person.forward(step_size)
    else:
        person.right(180) #if person is outside the borders it turns around
        person.forward(step_size)

def infect_random(people): 
    """
   Random person gets infected (a red color)
    people = a list of persons achieved from de function population()
    """
    infected = choice(people)
    infected.color('red')
    return infected

screen = Screen()

people = population(100)
person_characteristics(people)

infected_people = []
people_steps=[0 for _ in range (len(people))]
initial_infected = infect_random(people)
infected_people.append(initial_infected)


counted_infections = 1

for _ in range(10): # determines the number of steps = time
    for person in people:
        random_walk(person, 30, 400)
        people_steps[people.index(person)]+=1
        if people_steps[people.index(person)]==5 and person.pencolor()=='red':
            person.color('green')
            infected_people.remove(person) 
        for infected_person in infected_people:
            if person.pencolor() != 'red' and person.distance(infected_person) < 30:  #if a person gets close to the initial infected person it also
                person.color('red')                                                   #gets infected & added to the list of infected persons
                infected_people.append(person)
                people_steps[people.index(person)]=0
                break 


count_susceptible = len(people) - len(infected_people)                          #counts number of susceptible people
count_infected = len(infected_people)                                           #counts number of infected people

print(count_susceptible)
print(count_infected)

screen.exitonclick()
```

You can use an auxiliary array to save the number of people's steps. If you create it with the same size you can work with the indexes. For example:

people=[person1, person2, person3]

people_steps=[number_of_steps1, number_of_steps2, number_of_steps3]

This is just a graphical representation.

But it is better to do it with a class so that the number of steps is part of it as an attribute.

I hope this helps. If you have any suggestions or questions, please let me know.